Would thermal vias under an Inductor be effective at dissipating heat?
I'm designing a BMS board that will be capable of charging my 1S2P battery back. I'll be using the 21700 Li-Ion cells, which will mean my batter pack will have a total capacity of 10000 mAh. The Charging IC is the BQ24618, which used the buck converter topology for charging the batteries. The inductor I'm using is the Vishday IHLP2020CZER2R2M11. I'm expecting the inductor to rise about 30°C above ambient, since the inductor current will be 7.5 A, because of the buck converter topology.
So I wanted to do what I could to help dissipate some of that heat without having to go to a heatsink. My goal is to reduce the temperature rise to 15°C or lower above ambient. I have GND thermal vias with exposed copper under my inductor, and I wanted to know:

Will the GND thermal vias help lower the inductor temperature, even though the inductor doesn't have a exposed pad?
What risks do you see with this approach?





Remember that the heat has to go somewhere: if this is in a small sealed box it will be a lot different to inside something which is ventilated.  Can you tell us about the housing and any other environmental information you might have?

Have you checked to see if you can run tracks under the inductor you propose. You may need to dig a little deeper than the data sheet to find this out.

@jonathanjo This will be going inside a tightly packed 3D printed enclosure. The enclosure itself just just big enough to house the batteries, the BMS, and a separate power board. I'm not trying to remove the heat all together. I was just trying to see if I can transfer it from the Inductor to the GND plane

Those vias are going to do virtually nothing for you. At minimum, you would need a thermal interface between the inductor and your via field. But then you run into soldering/manufacturing problems. So don't do this.
The vast majority of heat could be removed through the inductor pads, so you can spread the heat with large copper pour fanning out from the pads. Use the copper pour real estate under the inductor to be the same net as the inductor pads.
A larger inductor will certainly lower the operating temperature at the expense of cost and solution footprint.

An article I read states that thermal vias don't do much. It's the amount of copper area that helps. Having copper area on different layers is also helpful.

@qrk Actually filled vias will help a lot. Just stacking layers won't help. I could have also mentioned to use heavier cooper. But that, too, is a sub-par work around instead of sizing the inductor properly at the beginning of the design.

You could use (electrically insulating) thermal interface material under the inductor to bridge the gap between the bottom of the inductor and the board. You might get a little better transfer by putting a no-go area for solder mask directly underneath as well. However, I second the idea for trying a bigger inductor and avoiding the headache altogether.
